# rails combo box with dynamic values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am having the following code to create a dynamic values for dropdown

```
<% @sub_category.dropdown_heads.each do |label| %>
        <div class="input">
            <div class="input-label"><label for="login"><%= label.head_name %></label></div>
            <div class="input-txt">
                <% options = options_from_collection_for_select(label.dropdown_lists, id, list_name) %>
                <%= select_tag :test_name, options %>
            </div>
        </div>
    <% end %>
```

The below code works

```
<% options = options_from_collection_for_select(@categories, 'id', 'name') %>
<%= f.select :category,  options %>
```

But why the above code throwing syntax error. How to modify my code to make it work.

Comment: post exact error message.

Comment: @stevanity `undefined local variable or method `id'` This is the error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select Tag:

```
select_tag :test_name,options_for_select(categories_options(@categories)), :style=>"styles goes here", :class=>"class added here"
```

options is in the format [[key, value], [key, value]]

You can use helper to generate it put it in application helper:

```
def categories_options categories
  categories.inject([]) do |memo, cat|
    memo << [cat.name.titleize, cat.id]
  end      
end
```

So its in format like

```
select_tag name, select options, other options
```

Comment: Ok got the output but what is happening  near `.inject` and `meme <<`. can you explain it. Any reference links?

Comment: Sure, here is a reference its a ruby function for array http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject  
inject is like looping put for special needs, and first param ([]) is the initialization which is memo inside the block it may be (0) if you sum some numbers

memo is now the array [] which intalizied in first param for inject, and ( << ) is like appending to array.